# jQuery Loop from a AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I'm building a tagger. After a user submits a tag, ajax returns:

```
{"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","tagsinserted":"BLAH, BLOOOW","returncode":"0"}
```

I want to take the tagsinserted and loop through it, and during each loop take the item in the list and insert it on the HTML page. suggestion on how to do this right?

Here is the current code:

```
$("#tag-post").click(function(){
    // Post $('#tag-input').val()
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tags/ajax/post-tag/',
        data: { newtaginput : $('#tag-input').val(), userid : $('#userid').val()},
        success: function(data) {
            // After posting
            alert('done');

        }
    });     

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#tag-post").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/tags/ajax/post-tag/',
    data: {newtaginput : $('#tag-input').val(), userid : $('#userid').val()},
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data.tagsinserted.split(', '), function(i, v) {
        $("<div></div>").text(v).appendTo("#tagHolder");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I like this. strange.. Here is the response:{"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","tagsinserted":"adadada","returncode":"0"}

I'm getting a tagsinserted is undefined?

Comment: @nobosh -  Add the `dataType: 'json',` option to your $.ajax call and `alert(data);` to your success call, what do you get?

Comment: It's still saying "data.tagsinserted is undefined" in Firebug.... Here is the response again: {"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","tagsinserted":"tettttt","returncode":"0"}

Comment: For Alert Data, it's showing up right I think: {"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","tagsinserted":"tettttt","returncode":"0"}

Comment: alert(data.tagsinserted); is altering undefined too

Comment: @nobosh - That's with `dataType:'json'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the tags by calling `data.tags.split(',')` and looping through the array it returns.

You can insert tags to the page by calling `$('<li />').text(tag).appendTo('someSelector')`.